# What is the simplest way to pause a loop by waiting for a user to press a key?

Tags: python

In Python, what is the simplest and most Pythonic way to pause a loop where a user keypress would restart the loop?  I'm looking at doing this just as a debugging aid, so that I can output some debug messages to stdout from within the loop without dumping a ton of text at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to limit the keypress to the Enter key, you can use `input` (`raw_input` in Python 2).  Otherwise, you'll need something platform specific.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    input() # Loop continues after <Enter> is pressed
```

Alternatively, you could use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), Python's built in debugger.

**See also** [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user).

Comment: I use `raw_input` as a debugging aid all the time :).  (perhaps I shouldn't say that too loudly ... the debugger police might find me).

Comment: Whoa, whoa, don't toss around accusations like that!

Comment: I only resort to using a debugger when I'm faced with a Heisenbug (a bug that disappears when you look at it).  Of course, I'm usually using fortran (which gdb unfortunately doesn't support all that well, or perhaps I'm just too lazy to make it work right) and MPI -- which makes it especially hard to figure out *which process* to attach the debugger to, etc...

Comment: I suppose that while we're on the topic of debuggers, somebody should mention that [python has one](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

Comment: Debuggers always have their place.  As an embedded guy that can't always **see** what is going on in code without a debugger, it is pleasing to be able to just dump something to the screen sometimes.

Comment: @mgilson, I'll check out pdb sometime.  Right now this is quicker.  Thanks!